# Using existing redis cache instance with elasticache

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I have an existing redis cache instance (1 node without sharding) on my local machine. How can I use this existing instance with elasticache to have failover protection (with 1 master and 2 replica nodes) ? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is to create a ElastiCache cluster and point your application to use that as your cache.

If moving existing cache data is needed, you can backup your current redis data and use that to seed the new ElastiCache cluster. more details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/backups-seeding-redis.html